# I have given the Header component, the search compoennt and the error

Tags: reactjs

I am implementing a search bar, so whenever a person enters a particular name it fetches the data from the API according to the data. Anybody who skilles in ReactJS latest version, please help me. I am sharing the search component , the header component and the error.

```
import { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const SearchBox = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const {search : queryString} = useLocation()
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("")

    useEffect(() => {
        const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(navigate.location.search).get("search")
        // const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(navigate.location.search).get("search") //have to fix this bug
        setSearch(queryParams || "")
    }, [queryString])

    const handleInput = e => {
        setSearch(e.target.value)
    }

    const handleFormSubmission = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        navigate({
            search: `search = ${search}`
        })
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmission}>
                    <input name="search" type="text"
                        id="search" 
                        placeholder="Enter product name, category"
                        value={search}
                        onChange={handleInput}
                        /> 
                    <button type="submit">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
                            className="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-search" 
                            width="20"
                            height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" 
                            strokeWidth="1.5" stroke="white" fill="none"
                            strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round">
                            <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                            <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="7" />
                            <line x1="21" y1="21" x2="15" y2="15" />
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </form>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
                    className="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-search" 
                    width="20"
                    height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" 
                    strokeWidth="1.5" stroke="white" 
                    fill="none" strokeLinecap="round"
                    strokeLinejoin="round">
                    <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="7" />
                    <line x1="21" y1="21" x2="15" y2="15" />
                </svg>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default SearchBox
```

//header component

```
import Cart from "../Cart"
import SearchBox from "../UI/Search"

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <header>
            <div className="nav-brand">
                <a to="/">
                    <span>AmaKart</span>
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
                        className="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-shopping-cart" 
                        width="30"
                        height="30" viewBox="0 0 24 24" 
                        strokeWidth="1.5" stroke="white" 
                        fill="none" strokeLinecap="round"
                        strokeLinejoin="round">
                        <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
                        <circle cx="6" cy="19" r="2" />
                        <circle cx="17" cy="19" r="2" />
                        <path d="M17 17h-11v-14h-2" />
                        <path d="M6 5l14 1l-1 7h-13" />
                    </svg>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div className="searchBox-container">
                <SearchBox/>
            </div>
            <div className="cart-container">
                <Cart/>
            </div>
        </header >
    )
}

export default Header
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jwo5u.png)

Please any one who knows React 16 version. Please help me.

Comment: Please include the error as formatted text.

Comment: You renamed “search”…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issues step from misunderstanding the `react-router` parts of the code.

The error is from `navigate.location.search`. You cannot get the query parameters from `navigate` because `navigate` is a function.  There is no `location` property on `navigate`.

You are using v6 so you can use the new [`useSearchParams` hook](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params).  With that hook, you no longer need to use `useNavigate` or `useLocation` in your code.

```
import { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

const SearchBox = () => {
    const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
    
    const urlSearch = searchParams.get("search");

    useEffect(() => {
        setSearch(urlSearch || "");
    }, [urlSearch]);

    const handleInput = e => {
        setSearch(e.target.value);
    }

    const handleFormSubmission = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setSearchParams({
            search: search
        });
    }
...
```